# finding and selecting the correct class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-selectors

I need to select .foo, however, there are two a tags with .foo, and I need to select the one only with .foo, and not the one with .foo.bar, how do I accomplish this?

```
<a class="foo bar">text</a>
<a class="foo">text</a>
```

the code I'm using to find .foo is

```
$(this).parents('.post').find('.foo').text('text');
```

Answer (score 1):

Some changes

1. Use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) instead of [.parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) to fetch the nearest ancestor
2. use the [:not()](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector to filter out `.bar` elements

Try

```
$(this).closest('.post').find('.foo:not(.bar)').text('text');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery .not(); http://api.jquery.com/not/

```
$(this).parents('.post').find('.foo').not('.bar').text('text');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(this).parents('.post').find('.foo').not('.bar').text('text');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just select with a class attribute:

```
.find('[class=foo]')
```

Answer (score 0):

You want `:not(selector)`:

```
$(this).parents('.post').find('.foo:not(.bar)').text('text');
```

See http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use .not() method:

$(this).parents('.post').find('.foo').not('.bar').text('text');

You can read more here:
http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/